# Facebook Codeless Event - iOS app does not connect to Events Manager

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-events

I'm trying to get Facebook Codeless Event to work, but I can't seem to connect my app to Events Manager.

Followed instruction from this article: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/codeless-app-events/#ios

After updating Facebook Core SDK to 4.39.1 and even including Marketing SDK just in case. Included  I went to Facebook app, and it did have check mark to say that my SDK version is compatible.

Then, the instruction say to open new session and shake the app, but even after vigorous shaking for more than 10 seconds, nothing happens in the app nor in the web browser.

Anybody know what can be done to properly set it up?

[image: connect-your-app-to-evens-manager]

Comment: I've had the same issue yesterday and today. I've tried everything - all the debugging options enabled in the SDK, versions 4.38.0 to 4.40.0 of the SDK, ensuring all the App IDs are consistent, and it still won't connect. I'm at a loss for where to go next trying to get this feature to work. It's probably worth noting that the "Test Events" feature of the "Event Manager" in Facebook for Business also doesn't show anything, so there seems to be some problems between those two Facebook features.

Comment: @tizaks on Android side it's working, but I still couldn't make it work on iOS. Are you using CocoaPod to install it? I tried to use Facebook sample iOS app and tried to connect to newly created Facebook app, and it didn't work. I'm out of options too.

Comment: No I've been using Carthage, but it doesn't seem to make a difference where you get the frameworks from.

I've reached out to Facebook's support and will update here once I hear back - they are currently investigating the issue.

Comment: @tizaks okay thanks. Let me know. For me, I'm downloading 4.39.1 iOS sdk from Facebook iOS SDK page.

Comment: @green0range Did you manage to solve this problem? I also have a connection problem.

Comment: @sarunw yes, by using Carthage to get the frameworks instead of directly downloading Facebook SDK from the website, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by not using Facebook SDK directly from website, but using Carthage to get the frameworks.

By getting 4.40.0 version from Carthage, shaking to connect to the Event Manager worked. There were some error creating events, but this is out of scope for this question, so I will mark this as solved.

Only setting that seems to be needed to connect correctly were: Facebook App Id and bundle id.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, it seems like the FBSDK has a different behaviour for the simulator.
Opening the simulator and executing a "Hardware" -> "Shake Gesture" worked for me.

Comment: for me it did not work on the device only the simulator